# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in file

Tags: php, laravel

ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in file.

sorry if i dont't understand that much, I just started learning Laravel, can someone please help me, I want to show the order data with the user id and course id. My code is like this

```
    public function create(Request $request){
        $user = $request->input('user');
        $course = $request->input('course');

        $order = Order::create([
            'user_id' => $user['id'],
            'course_id' => $course['id']
        ]);

        return response()->json($order);
    }
```

and got an error in post man like this
`ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the string as an array first, and the value of `$user`  or `$course` is coming in as `null` meaning no value is being sent in the request.

You should add some sort of validation first before you try to save the data to the database table.

```
   public function create(Request $request){
    $user = $request->input('user');
    $course = $request->input('course');
    if(!$user || !$course){
           return response()->json(['error' => true], 422); //do some validation response error or use laravels validation methods
    }

    $order = Order::create([
        'user_id' => $user,
        'course_id' =>  $course
    ]);

    return response()->json($order);
}
```